# Add editors to Google Docs without allowing them to see the document

Tags: google-drive, permissions

For our organization I'd like to have an online Google Docs Spreadsheet to which all co-workers can submit info, but only the owner (in this case me) can see the document.

I've taken a look at the privacy and sharing settings, but the only thing I came across, was the drop-down list that allows you to set someone as either a Viewer, Editor or Owner.

I presume this means I can't accomplish what I'm trying to do here, but I'm just asking to be sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do it as a form, like this one: https://spreadsheets0.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEN6SDhuY3J1dVZxb09DcURqcU8tdEE6MA

Otherwise, as soandos said, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 8):

This is impossible.

The reason why it is impossible is because one cannot actually edit a document they can't see. The best they can do (as you said) is try to submit input. But that requires knowing where the input would go, something they can't know as they can't see the document.

Answer (score 2):

If depends on what kind of information you want people to submit. If each person is submitting unique information like, an answer to a question, then you can do it by using the Google Spreadsheet + Forms ( no html knowledge required ) but if you are looking for people to be able to submit information based on somethign another coworker has submitted then Google Docs is not the right solution.